# Delphi strToint64 initial with zero value

Tags: string, delphi-xe8, int64

in Delphi XE8 I have to convert a '03213213210' string into an int64
       `a:=strToint64('03213213210');`

I receive a = 3213213210; How can i receive?  a = 03213213210;
Help me. Thank you.

Comment: Your variable `a` is a numeric value. There is no concept of leading zeros. That only makes sense when you represent the numeric value as a string. Your question is therefore based on a false premise.

Comment: I have to return a value to a class defined by WS WSDL I imported into delphi and a data type pIva = int64. This value is defined in the int64 class. I have to send '03213213210' 
that is the VAT number.

Comment: @carmeloconny then int64 is the wrong type to use, you need a string instead

Comment: yes I turned into string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Int64` is a numeric value. It holds a number. Numbers have no concept of formatting, leading zeros, representation base etc. A number is just a number.

Concepts such as binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal have no impact on the value of the number, just its representation. Similarly, formatting requirements such as a set number of digits are not related to the value, but are a property of formatting of the value for display.

In short, leading zeros are not a property of a number. Your `Int64` variable contains the number. When you choose to display it, you may opt to enforce a set number of digits, for instance by padding with leading zeros to achieve that number. But that's not a property of the number, the `Int64` variable. That's a property of how you choose to display it.

So, if you really need to send the value as an `Int64`, then you have nothing more to do. If it needs to be displayed with 11 digits, with zero left padding, then that formatting is the responsibility of whoever displays it. On the other hand, it is possible that you should be holding the value as a string in order to preserve the formatting.

I can't tell which of the two options above is what you need to do, but I can be quite sure that trying to store leading zeros in an `Int64` is not the solution because that is not possible.

Comment: I must send 03213213210 How can i add padding left? This int64 always has 11 digits. es.: 00012345678

Comment: I can't just keep repeating myself. Do you know that `1=01`?